# Should I downgrade gcc for legacy code?

Tags: debian, drivers, gcc, c

I inherited a legacy system that looks like this.

```
$ uname -a
Linux pos-sthlm-globe-as-209 2.4.19-dxx #10 Thu Dec 22 15:47:12 CET 2005 i686 GNU/Linux
niklros@pos-sthlm-globe-as-209:~$ gcc --version
2.95.4
```

It has source code that I can build (it is a 32-bit driver for a PCI card that is used):

```
# make clean
test -z "mtn.o" || rm -f mtn.o
rm -rf .libs _libs
rm -f *.o core *.core
rm -f *.lo
pos-sthlm-globe-as-209:~/mtn/dxxmtn# ls
BusMastHostApi.h   bmhostif_parsed.h  proc.c        uaa.c
Makefile       cc.c           queue.c       uaa.h
Makefile.am    ct812.c        ram.c     uaa_msg.c
Makefile.in    drawbridge.c       ringbuf.c     uniporte_parsed.c
PORT           dump.c         src       uniporte_parsed.h
TODO           log.c          telem.c       untar
UniPorte.h     main.c         telem_cmd.c   usr
aaa        memring.c          telem_cons.c  vpd.c
ac         mtn            telem_misc.c
bc.c           mtn2100.rc         tmp
bmhostif_parsed.c  mtn_poll.c         tty.c
pos-sthlm-globe-as-209:~/mtn/dxxmtn# make
if [ ! -f uniporte_parsed.c -a ! -f uniporte_parsed.h ]; then \
    rm -f uniporte_parsed.c uniporte_parsed.h; \
    ../utils/grabenum.pl /usr/local/dxx/include/UniPorte.h -header > uniporte_parsed.c; \
    for enum in uniporte_managed_object_indices uniport_disconnect_reason_enumeration uniporte_port_state_enumeration ; do \
        echo "Grabbing enumerator $enum from /usr/local/dxx/include/UniPorte.h into uniporte_parsed.c..."; \
        ../utils/grabenum.pl /usr/local/dxx/include/UniPorte.h $enum -array >> uniporte_parsed.c; \
        echo "extern char *$enum[];" >> uniporte_parsed.h; \
    ...
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/sched.h:770: warning: called from here
/bin/sh ../libtool --mode=link gcc  -O -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DMODVERSIONS -Wall -Winline        -o mtn.o -r uniporte_parsed.o bmhostif_parsed.o uaa.o uaa_msg.o main.o bc.o cc.o mtn_poll.o tty.o ram.o vpd.o drawbridge.o ct812.o dump.o telem.o telem_cmd.o telem_misc.o queue.o ringbuf.o telem_cons.o log.o  
mkdir .libs
/usr/bin/ld -r -o mtn.o uniporte_parsed.o bmhostif_parsed.o uaa.o uaa_msg.o main.o bc.o cc.o mtn_poll.o tty.o ram.o vpd.o drawbridge.o ct812.o dump.o telem.o telem_cmd.o telem_misc.o queue.o ringbuf.o telem_cons.o log.o   
pos-sthlm-globe-as-209:~/mtn/dxxmtn# ls
BusMastHostApi.h   ct812.c   proc.c        tmp
Makefile       ct812.o   queue.c       tty.c
Makefile.am    drawbridge.c  queue.o       tty.o
Makefile.in    drawbridge.o  ram.c         uaa.c
PORT           dump.c    ram.o         uaa.h
TODO           dump.o    ringbuf.c     uaa.o
UniPorte.h     log.c     ringbuf.o     uaa_msg.c
aaa        log.o     src           uaa_msg.o
ac         main.c    telem.c       uniporte_parsed.c
bc.c           main.o    telem.o       uniporte_parsed.h
bc.o           memring.c     telem_cmd.c   uniporte_parsed.o
bmhostif_parsed.c  mtn       telem_cmd.o   untar
bmhostif_parsed.h  mtn.o     telem_cons.c  usr
bmhostif_parsed.o  mtn2100.rc    telem_cons.o  vpd.c
cc.c           mtn_poll.c    telem_misc.c  vpd.o
cc.o           mtn_poll.o    telem_misc.o
pos-sthlm-globe-as-209:~/mtn/dxxmtn#
```

Now I try to replicate it in a Virtual Box VM on my local machine but it seems I fail and I think it is because gcc is version 3 and not version 2.

```
# uname -a     
Linux debian 2.4.27-3-386 #1 Wed Dec 6 00:38:33 UTC 2006 i686 GNU/Linux
debian:/home/developer/mtn-copy/mtn-copy/mtn/dxxmtn# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 3.3.5 (Debian 1:3.3.5-13)
Copyright (C) 2003 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

debian:/home/developer/mtn-copy/mtn-copy/mtn/dxxmtn# make clean
test -z "mtn.o" || rm -f mtn.o
rm -rf .libs _libs
rm -f *.o core *.core
rm -f *.lo
debian:/home/developer/mtn-copy/mtn-copy/mtn/dxxmtn# ls
aaa        gcc-2.95.3.tar  proc.c    tty.c
ac         log.c       queue.c   uaa.c
bc.c           main.c      ram.c     uaa.h
bmhostif_parsed.c  Makefile    ringbuf.c     uaa_msg.c
bmhostif_parsed.h  Makefile.am     src       UniPorte.h
BusMastHostApi.h   Makefile.in     telem.c   uniporte_parsed.c
cc.c           memring.c       telem_cmd.c   uniporte_parsed.h
ct812.c        mtn         telem_cons.c  untar
drawbridge.c       mtn2100.rc      telem_misc.c  usr
dump.c         mtn_poll.c      tmp       usr-src-linux-include
gcc-2.95.3     PORT        TODO      vpd.c
debian:/home/developer/mtn-copy/mtn-copy/mtn/dxxmtn# make
if [ ! -f uniporte_parsed.c -a ! -f uniporte_parsed.h ]; then \
  rm -f uniporte_parsed.c uniporte_parsed.h; \
 ...
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/signal.h:205: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:457: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_c_and_count_memset'
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/signal.h:149: warning: called from here
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I/usr/local/dxx/include -I../mtnadm -I/usr/src/linux/include -include /usr/src/linux/include/linux/modversions.h    -O -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DMODVERSIONS -Wall -Winline         -c telem_misc.c
In file included from mtn/mtn.h:436,
         from mtn/telem_misc.h:28,
         from telem_misc.c:34:
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/malloc.h:4:2: warning: #warning linux/malloc.h is deprecated, use linux/slab.h instead.
In file included from mtn/mtn.h:443,
         from mtn/telem_misc.h:28,
         from telem_misc.c:34:
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/uaccess.h: In function `__constant_copy_from_user':
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:457: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_c_and_count_memset'
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/uaccess.h:561: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/siginfo.h: At top level:
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:222: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_memcpy'
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/siginfo.h:223: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:222: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_memcpy'
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/siginfo.h:226: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:457: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_c_and_count_memset'
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/signal.h:149: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:457: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_c_and_count_memset'
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/signal.h:161: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:457: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_c_and_count_memset'
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/signal.h:193: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:457: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_c_and_count_memset'
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/signal.h:205: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:457: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_c_and_count_memset'
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/signal.h:149: warning: called from here
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I/usr/local/dxx/include -I../mtnadm -I/usr/src/linux/include -include /usr/src/linux/include/linux/modversions.h    -O -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DMODVERSIONS -Wall -Winline         -c queue.c
In file included from mtn/mtn.h:436,
         from mtn/queue.h:54,
         from queue.c:70:
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/malloc.h:4:2: warning: #warning linux/malloc.h is deprecated, use linux/slab.h instead.
In file included from mtn/mtn.h:443,
         from mtn/queue.h:54,
         from queue.c:70:
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/uaccess.h: In function `__constant_copy_from_user':
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:457: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_c_and_count_memset'
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/uaccess.h:561: warning: called from here
queue.c: In function `mtn_data_queue_add':
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/uaccess.h:557: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_copy_from_user'
queue.c:367: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:222: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_memcpy'
queue.c:379: warning: called from here
queue.c: In function `mtn_data_queue_get':
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:222: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_memcpy'
queue.c:443: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/siginfo.h: At top level:
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:222: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_memcpy'
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/siginfo.h:223: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:222: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_memcpy'
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/siginfo.h:226: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:457: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_c_and_count_memset'
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/signal.h:149: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:457: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_c_and_count_memset'
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/signal.h:161: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:457: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_c_and_count_memset'
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/signal.h:193: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:457: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_c_and_count_memset'
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/signal.h:205: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:457: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_c_and_count_memset'
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/signal.h:149: warning: called from here
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I/usr/local/dxx/include -I../mtnadm -I/usr/src/linux/include -include /usr/src/linux/include/linux/modversions.h    -O -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DMODVERSIONS -Wall -Winline         -c ringbuf.c
ringbuf.c:43:19: errno.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ringbuf.c:45:
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/uaccess.h: In function `__constant_copy_from_user':
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:457: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_c_and_count_memset'
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/uaccess.h:561: warning: called from here
In file included from mtn/mtn.h:436,
         from ringbuf.c:47:
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/malloc.h:4:2: warning: #warning linux/malloc.h is deprecated, use linux/slab.h instead.
ringbuf.c: In function `mtn_ringbuf_readline':
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:222: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_memcpy'
ringbuf.c:121: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:222: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_memcpy'
ringbuf.c:123: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:222: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_memcpy'
ringbuf.c:124: warning: called from here
ringbuf.c: In function `mtn_ringbuf_read':
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:222: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_memcpy'
ringbuf.c:151: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:222: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_memcpy'
ringbuf.c:153: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:222: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_memcpy'
ringbuf.c:154: warning: called from here
ringbuf.c: In function `mtn_ringbuf_read_to_user':
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/uaccess.h:548: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_copy_to_user'
ringbuf.c:181: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/uaccess.h:548: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_copy_to_user'
ringbuf.c:185: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/uaccess.h:548: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_copy_to_user'
ringbuf.c:185: warning: called from here
ringbuf.c: In function `mtn_ringbuf_write':
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:222: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_memcpy'
ringbuf.c:214: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:222: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_memcpy'
ringbuf.c:216: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:222: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_memcpy'
ringbuf.c:217: warning: called from here
ringbuf.c: In function `mtn_ringbuf_write_from_user':
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/uaccess.h:557: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_copy_from_user'
ringbuf.c:245: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/uaccess.h:557: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_copy_from_user'
ringbuf.c:249: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/uaccess.h:557: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_copy_from_user'
ringbuf.c:249: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/siginfo.h: At top level:
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:222: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_memcpy'
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/siginfo.h:223: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:222: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_memcpy'
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/siginfo.h:226: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:457: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_c_and_count_memset'
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/signal.h:149: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:457: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_c_and_count_memset'
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/signal.h:161: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:457: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_c_and_count_memset'
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/signal.h:193: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:457: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_c_and_count_memset'
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/signal.h:205: warning: called from here
/usr/src/linux/include/asm/string.h:457: warning: inlining failed in call to `__constant_c_and_count_memset'
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/signal.h:149: warning: called from here
make: *** [ringbuf.o] Error 1
debian:/home/developer/mtn-copy/mtn-copy/mtn/dxxmtn#
```

Is my conclusion correct that the failed build in the VM is because of the difference in gcc versions or is there some other reason for the failed build?

Comment: BTW, you can have *several* versions of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) installed at once.

Comment: @StephenKitt It seems that there are only warnings but still a failed build. The make output is too many lines for a question but I pasted it https://pastebin.com/e3q1NHJg My versions of Linux differ very little, both are v 2,4.x

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Nice. I hope that is why I get an error after the build and that I only need to install gcc v2.9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The severe error you've got is from the preprocessor phase (for some `#include <errno.h>` line):

> ringbuf.c:43:19: errno.h: No such file or directory

(the other diagnostics are just warnings; you should understand each of them, but you could -probably wrongly- choose to ignore them; I recommend improving the code to get no warnings with a *recent* version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked with `-Wall -Wextra`, currently [GCC 7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/) in july 2017)

On my Debian system, `<errno.h>` header is in `/usr/include/errno.h` provided by the `libc6-dev` package. You should install something equivalent.

As I commented, you can have *several* versions of `gcc` on your system (on my recent Debian, I can install `gcc-5` and `gcc-6` & `gcc-7` packages, and I also could compile and build some recent version under `/usr/local/bin/`).
However, `<errno.h>` is not a compiler-supplied header, so installing another [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)  (e.g. downgrading it) won't help.

Comment: Wonderful. Now it seems like it compiles without error.

Comment: Hah, the error actually appears in the part quoted in the question...