# How to locate missing C code

Tags: debian

I inherited a legacy development system which is poorly documented and the source code is not known if it still is available.

Now I could locate some of the source code and actually build one part of the system.

I wonder if I can find the rest of the source code and if there is any better way than `locate *.c` and manually inspecting the files (that's how I found part of the code).

There are 3 machines and only one where I found the source code that seems to be a development machine. It also has 61 `.deb` archives that seems to be the packaged versions of the projects, but looking into the `.deb` archives shows that the source is not in the archives or at least not where I looked.

Is there a good way to "scan" an entire drive for source code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This won’t answer your more general question, but in your specific case, since you have packages on the system, it’s worth looking for the corresponding source code:

```
find / -name \*.orig.tar\* -o -name \*.dsc
```

This will look for source archives named in the way the Debian package building tools expect, and source package control files. If you find those, look for `.debian.tar*` or `.diff.gz` files alongside them. All these files combined would give you the source code and the build rules, along with all the package metadata.

You could also look for unpacked control files:

```
find / -name control
```

These would typically live in the `debian` subdirectory of a package’s source, which should contain everything you need to rebuild the package from source.

Comment: also: `find / -wholename '*/debian/rules'`.   or (faster, if mlocate is installed) `locate -r /debian/rules$`

Comment: @cas I’m trying to play it safe here, I’ve seen some very odd setups for building Debian packages. `locate` would be faster, but I’ve been disappointed in the past running it on recovered systems which had been cleaned up — the `locate` database still new about source code which was gone. (That can still be useful information if backups are available...)

Comment: Going by https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382857/ , these are not Debian packages.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the source is/was versioned with CVS. Maybe I can look for old cvs directories(?)

Comment: @JdeBP I was going by “It also has 61 `.deb` archives that seems to be the packaged versioned of the projects” (sic).

Comment: @DjDac that would work too, `find / -name CVS` would find checked-out copies of the code.

Comment: I get a strange error running find: `find: /proc/361/fd: No such file or directory`

Comment: @cas I get these error msgs: `find: invalid predicate -wholename` and `locate: invalid option -- r`

Comment: @DjDac that’s fine, just `find` trying to read files in `/proc` which disappear between the time `find` builds its list of files and the time it reads them. You can skip `/proc` entirely.

Comment: @DjDac doh.  sarge is old and has old version of findutils, so no `-wholename` in `find` and no `-r` in `locate`. sorry about that.   you can achieve similar with `locate / | grep ....`

Comment: sarge's `locate` should work with just `locate '*debian/rules'`. From `man locate` on my woody VM: `If a pattern does contain metacharacters, locate only displays file names that match the pattern exactly.` (tested there, too).

Comment: I would search for a local git repo too

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I could run the above commands to make sure that I looked everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a combination of scripts for working with source files. Just as the answer above this will not solve exactly your case, but searching for symbols can help in locating source files.

The following is added to `bashrc`:

```
function list-code-files() {
    find -type f \( \
        -name '*.cpp' -o \
        -name '*.java' -o \
        -name '*.php' -o \
        -name '*.[chS]' -o \
        -name 'Makefile' -o \
        -name '*.mk' \
        \) -print0
}

function csym() {
    list-code-files | xargs -0 grep -ne "$1"
}
```

Then I can list source files using `list-code-files | xargs -0 echo`, or search for symbols using `csym some-symbol-regexeg`